# can we use preposition "by" with past participles used as adjectives to give similar meaning of preposition "by" used with passive voice sentences?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles

I know that in passive voice sentences, "by" can be used to imply one making the action. For instance,

- He was attacked by a lion. A lion attacked him so "by" shows the one making the action.

My question is can we use the preposition "by" to give the same meaning above when we use "by" with past participles used as adjectives? For instance, after I push the submit button for my assignment in an electronic system, it says

- Your work is submitted. Can we say "your work is submitted by you?", is it grammatically correct?

For instance, assume I paid someone for doing my homework for once (not a general case that is done usually but just for one time).

- After my homework is done may I say "my homework is done by my friend?". Is it grammatically correct?

If my examples are not grammatically correct, again is there a usage of by with past participles used as adjectives in which "by" has the same meaning with the usage of "by" with passive voice sentences?

Comment: They're the same, yes, but they become clumsier yet in the examples you gave. "A good time was had by all" is a standard example of sentences in passive that are not wrong, but not happy, either.

Comment: The person performing the action in a passive sentence or utterance is called the agent. was/were + action verb + by [agent].

Comment: Your examples all sound non-idiomatic to me. We would say "my home work *was* done by my friend" to say how it was done, we wouldn't use "*is* done by my friend" to describe its state now.

Comment: "My home work is done by my friend" sounds more like it's describing a general process -- your friend always does your homework for you.